# CSS : centering a div and mixing pixels and percents

Tags: css, center, pixel, percentage

I would like to have a `<div>` centered in my page, with `width = a % + b` pixels.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: If you google you will get lots of answer. There are plenty of answers in stack as well.

Comment: Are you sure ? Even with both : centering and width with pixels and percentages ?

Comment: To mix different measuring scales you could use `-webkit-calc()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give its parent `div`, `align="center"`
like:

```
<div align="center">
   content
</div>
```

Comment: Is `align` a CSS3 property ? How at the same time, set the width with a mix and percentages and pixels ? I am looking for javascript-free solution.