# How to center a div with CSS?

Tags: css, center, centering

I am learning HTML/CSS, and so far, I still have difficulties with CSS, especially when it comes to positioning.

For instance, can anyone explain to me why the following doesn't work?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
    ​#main{
        background-color : blue;   
        height : 50px;
        width : 30px;
    }
    .centerer{
        margin : 0 auto;}

    ​
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="centerer">
        <div id="main">
        </div>
    </div>​​​​​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks ЯegDwight for editing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/b1yPPTXP)***

Now define your `#main` **ID** `display:inline-block` and give to `text-align:center` in your `.centerer` **class**

Write to do this as like this

**Css**

```
#main {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
    .centerer{
        margin : 0 auto;
width:200px;
  background:red;
  text-align:center;
}
```

**Your html**

```
<div class="centerer">
        <div id="main">fgasdfds fsd ds fsd
        </div>
    </div>
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/b1yPPTXP)***

Comment: Your code does not work either ! It's driving me nuts ! CSS : ever seen such a weird langage !

Comment: @Colas now define text-align:center as like this demo two http://tinkerbin.com/65XQOzej

Comment: But there is no blue... I would say your code does not work :(

Comment: Yes, but what I want is 50*30 blue block centered in my page and that the centering comes from a parent.

Comment: @Colas If all these **working** examples stop working after you try them in your code, don't you think that _your_ code is probably messing it up.

Comment: Yes for sure ! But if you look at tinkerbin.com/65XQOzej , it's not at all what I want to do !

Comment: This : http://tinkerbin.com/PtCMHC93 (Demo one of the answer) is not working and nobody can explain why

Answer (score 0):

For that to work you need to give `.center` a definite width, or else the browser can't compute the margins for left and right. The following should work:

```
.centerer{
        margin : 0 auto;
   width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does. It's incredibly basic.

Comment: So it means my code bugs elsewhere, because when I open it with Chrome, the result is a blank page !

Comment: Are you sure? Does your div id="main" actually contain any content??

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired resulth through `margin:auto;`

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

        <div id="main">afdafdaf
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
margin:auto;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  text-align:center;
}
```

[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/xrpfEm0b)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `centerer` div a width.

Answer (score 0):

`.centerer` *is* centred, it has `width: auto` (the default) so is as wide as its container, and it looks the same as if it was left- or right-aligned.

If you want to centre `#main` then you have to set auto margins on `#main` itself.

Comment: Yes, I know, but my point is that I want to center .centerer and that the content appears in it ! (I need to fix different margins for #main, actually). I cant understand why it doesn't work !! Isnt .centerer supposed to be centered in `body` ? See my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230107/css-centering-a-div-and-mixing-pixels-and-percents

Comment: @Colas — Paragraph one of my answer addresses centring centerer. Paragraph two addresses centring the content of centerer.

Comment: why is .centered not centered relatively to <body> ? Why dont the centering property propagate to children ?

Comment: @Colas — .centred **is** centred relative to the body. You just can't see it because it is the same width as the body. If you centre a block, then its block-level children are not automatically centred inside it because it is comparatively rare that people want that sort of layout.

Comment: I thought that .centerer would take the minimum width, with respect to what it contains. But, it seems it takes 100% of body. Do you know the rule for the auto dimensions of a block ? Thanks

Comment: If `width` is `auto` then the width of the element is whatever is left in the content area of the parent after margin, padding and border have been accounted for.

Comment: But, if you consider <div> test </div>, the width of my div relates to its own content, without any consideration to the parent ?

Comment: No, [it doesn't](http://jsbin.com/atinoj/1/) (hence why the background colour extends to the width of the container and not just the width of the text).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Unless I choose `display: inline` for this 'div'. Now, imagine I add `display: inline` to `.centerer` : is it going to work (ie : `.centerer` is centering inside `<body>` and has the width of `#main`) ?

Comment: No. auto margins don't centre things that display inline. (And trying to have `display: block` things inside `display: inline` things is weird anyway).

Comment: Do you know how to do to have a *centered* div whose width is of the form `a% + b px` ?

Answer (score 0):

You want #main to be in center, so you have to give `margin:0 auto;` to #main.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DeepakKamat/Ceuhn/5/)

The HTML :

```
<div class="centerer">
        <div id="main"></div>
</div>​
```

And the CSS :

```
.centerer {background-color : red;}

#main {
        background-color : blue;   
        height : 50px;
        width : 30px;
        margin : 0 auto;
    }
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `margin:0 auto` will centre the DIV fine, but you have to supply a width in order for it to work properly.

For example, in CSS:

```
div {
    width: 900px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here is your HTML/CSS code updated so that the DIVs will be centrally aligned.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">
#main {
    background-color: blue;
    height : 50px;
    width : 30px;
}

.centerer {
    margin : 0 auto;
    width: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="centerer">
        <div id="main">
    </div>
</div>​​​​​

</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you could get rid of the `.centerer` div, instead just making the `#main` div centered itself, by applying the same CSS - you've already got a width defined so just add `margin:0 auto;`. However, if you want other items centered within the `.centerer` container, keep things as they are.